# Duvidas sobre formatações de colunas no gridView

Tags: c#, sql-select, entity-framework-6, grid

Oi, tenho umas duvidas sobre formatação das colunas em um gridview, tenho um gridView que é populado por da dados vindo de uma tabela no banco de dados, as colunas e linha são geradas automaticamente, tenho um método que realiza a consulta no banco de dados:

```
public GridView exibeCarteira(string cepf, ref GridView tb)
    {
        try
        {
            bancotccEntities bc = new bancotccEntities();

            var crt = from cart in bc.carteira
                      where cart.cpf == cepf
                      select new
                      {
                          Codigo = cart.codigo,
                          Valor = cart.valoracao,
                          Quantidade = cart.qtdacao,
                          Total = cart.vtotalacao,
                          Valor_Gasto = cart.vinvestido

                      };
            tb.DataSource = crt.ToList() ;
            tb.DataBind();
            return tb;
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            throw new Exception(e1.Message.ToString());

        }

    }
```

este método é chamdo pelo método :

```
public GridView mostraCarteira(string cpf, ref GridView gv)
    {
        try
        {
            ManipulaBanco mp = new ManipulaBanco();
            return mp.exibeCarteira(cpf, ref  gv);
        }
        catch (Exception e4)
        {

            throw new Exception(e4.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Que é chamado pelo método da minha gridview que exibe as informações para o usuário

```
 public partial class ExibeCarteira : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string cpf;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                exibirCarteira();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
    private void exibirCarteira()
    {
        try
        {
            cpf = "98765432101";
            Trataformes tf = new Trataformes();
            this.gvcarteira = tf.mostraCarteira(cpf, ref gvcarteira);

        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {

            throw new Exception(e1.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
    protected void gvcarteira_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

A minha duvida é como  posso formatar as informações que serão exibidas em cada coluna em formatos como data, dinheiro, definir a quantidade de 0 após a virgula, etc. 
tentei editar as colunas mas como elas são geradas automaticamente elas não aparecem para serem formatadas conforme a figura abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
 posso adicionar as colunas do tipo BoundField e formatar elas?  mesmo que a minha gridview gere as colunas automaticamente? se for possível eu consigo formartar  na maneira que eu preciso mas se não for possível  tem alguma outra maneira?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim existe essa possibilidade, na [DataFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), tendo ai inúmeras configurações de formato de dados.

***Class Fulano***

```
public class Fulano
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public Decimal Valor { get; set; }
}
```

***GridView***

*Coloque no Gridview `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` quando você configura manualmente todos os campos (Edit Columns).*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Configurando o campo Data:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Código gerado depois de todas as configurações:***

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridDados" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" ItemType="WebAppDiegoWebForms.Fulano">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Codigo" HeaderText="Código" DataFormatString="{0:0000}"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Nome" HeaderText="Nome" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Data" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Data" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Valor" DataFormatString="{0:N2}" HeaderText="Valor" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

O `DataField="Data"` tem um `DataFormatString="{0:d}"` que seria a data abreviada, e o `DataField="Valor"` um `DataFormatString="{0:N2}"` que é número com duas casas decimais, se precisar adicionar mais casas é só aumentar o 2 para o número correspondente.

***Lembrete:***

Configure também o seu `Globalization` para *pt-BR* no seu `web.config` que é o padrão Brasileiro de moeda, data, etc.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

***Resultado:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse [link tem os formatos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), então, se basea por está tabela.

*Referência:*

- [Propriedade BoundField.DataFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Usar globalization no Web.Config e CultureInfo para formatar data e moeda em vários idiomas no ASP.NET / C#](http://cbsa.com.br/post/usar-globalization-no-webconfig-e-cultureinfo-para-formatar-data-e-moeda-em-varios-idiomas-no-aspnet-c.aspx)

Comment: se por o AutoGenerateColumns="False", tenho que adicionar as colunas  via edite colunas Não estou certo ?

Comment: Se você colocar AutoGenerateColumns="False", ai você adiciona as colunas manualmente, no Add Column na setinha ao lado do GridView

Comment: Mais uma duvida os dados virão do banco de dados na configuração do primeiro método da pergunta, esses dado se mantem  correto ? só adiciono a quantidade certa de coluna

Comment: Isso, agora você deve relacionar, os dados que vem do banco com os que vão aparecer no `Gridview`. Exemplo: tem 10 campos que vem do banco são 10 *Columns* no seu GridView, com as formatações nos campos que precisam, os que não precisam deixe em branco o `DataFormatString`.

Comment: Ok resolvido, obrigado pela ajuda, só uma dica se for possível com faço para alteras as cores da font?